# Git Remote Code Execution vulnerabilities as of January 17, 2023

Tags: git, github

GitHub Blog: https://github.blog/2023-01-17-git-security-vulnerabilities-announced-2

Git has 3 new Remote Code Execution vulnerabilities.

It's said in the blog that Git was already patched by version 2.39.1. But, I don't think they explicitly said that GitHub Desktop has upgraded its embedded Git to 2.39.1.

GitHub Desktop Release Notes: https://desktop.github.com/release-notes

As per January 18th release comes with upgraded git version 2.35.6. The latest January 25th release does not include the new embedded git version 2.39.1. **Am I right to assume that GitHub Desktop still has unpatched version of Git?**

And lastly, GitHub Blog said that they scanned all repositories in GitHub.com and found no evidence concerning the site being used as an attack vector. **But, do we also have sources that GitLab did the same on their side?**

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerabilities were not only fixed in 2.39.1 The fixes were also backported to earlier versions. Specifically, v2.35.6 also fixes  CVE-2022-41903 and CVE-2022-23521.

See the columns Patched versions on https://github.com/git/git/security/advisories/GHSA-c738-c5qq-xg89 and https://github.com/git/git/security/advisories/GHSA-475x-2q3q-hvwq

Thus, **the GitHub Desktop release 3.1.4 of January 18th 2023, which upgrades the embedded Git to 2.35.6, already fixed these issues**.

CVE-2022-41953 would appear not to be included there, but that only covers cloning on Windows using git gui (which may not be included/used by GitHub Desktop?)